# Check if object value inside array, already exists in a different array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, firebase

Plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/jXdwOQR2YLnIWv8j02Yp

I'm using angular to build a view which has a list of users in the main container (array-A) and a sidebar of users which host any 'selected' users (array-B).

The first one (A) has all the users.

[{ $$hashKey: "00F", id: "118207f5e52c3eb619a8760bc08c8224", username: "John Smith" }, 
{ $$hashKey: "00G", id: "9c2d6f31c88e7a654e64bd0d3371360a", username: "Fredy Rincon" },
{ ... }]

The second one (B) has the users that are already selected (Firebase db) and through which the sidebar is pre-populated. If the users are already selected then they appear here exactly as they do in array-A.

My goal is to be able to add and remove objects from array-B / Sidebar view, by clicking on items from array-A in the main container.

The below is as close as I've been able to get but it doesn't take into account the existing users which are pre-populated onto the sidebar, and just adds and removes items that are already present, as if they weren't there.

For your reference:

$scope.selectedUsers = array-B

user = object in array-A

```
$scope.selectUser = function (user) {
  console.log($scope.selectedUsers.indexOf(user))
  if ($scope.selectedUsers.indexOf(user) === -1 ) {
    $scope.selectedUsers.push(user);
    console.log($scope.selectedUsers);
  } else {
    $scope.selectedUsers.splice($scope.selectedUsers.indexOf(user), 1);
    console.log($scope.selectedUsers);
  }
};
```

I really have no idea as to how to approach a solution for this, would really appreciate any help possible.

Thanks.

Comment: So, they have the same object properties (outside of Angular stuff) in both arrays? id's, username's, etc?

Comment: That is correct Marc.

Comment: Have you thought about using underscorejs? http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual

Comment: I just posted an answer using `Array.prototype.reduce` but Underscore could be used as well of course. But I think they'd want to use `_.reduce` here rather than `_.isEqual`.

Comment: Thanks Marc. I've also added a plunker for my current progress. I also need to be able to remove the items on click. The plunker might provide a bit more clarity. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to check users before adding:

```
$scope.add = function(user){
  var match = $scope.selectedUsers.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return (user.id === curr.id) || prev;
  }, false);
  console.log(match ? 'match' : 'no match');
  if (!match) $scope.selectedUsers.push(user);
};
```

... where your view looks like:

```
<p ng-repeat="user in users">{{user.username}} <a ng-click="add(user)">+</a></p>
```

To remove users from the `selectedUsers` array, use [`Array.prototype.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
$scope.remove = function(index){
  $scope.selectedUsers.splice(index, 1)
}
```

...where your view looks like:

```
<p ng-repeat="selectedUser in selectedUsers">{{selectedUser.username}}
<a ng-click="remove($index)">--</a></p>
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/D2qmrFTkCeeOa669nyzw?p=preview)

Comment: This is great and takes me half way there. How do I remove an item that is matched? Thank you lots!

Comment: Thanks Marc. Unfortunately the interaction of adding and removing needs to come solely from the main container, similar to the plunker I made here: http://plnkr.co/edit/jXdwOQR2YLnIWv8j02Yp

I really appreciate your help anyway, this at least gets me somewhere. If you do think of another possible approach please let me know.

I tried modifying your solution to

     if (!match) {
        $scope.selectedUsers.push(user)
      } else {
        $scope.selectedUsers.splice(user, 1);

but of course this doesn't work because the pre-populated items are not part of the selectedUsers array. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Since it appears that each of your objects has a unique string ID, a viable approach is to store only the IDs in array-A and array-B, store a dictionary of the full data objects in a shared service, and use an angular filter to look up the full data object by ID when needed for presentation, etc.

Comment: This is compatible with (or could be an extension of) my answer, and it certainly would make your solution more DRY friendly.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I didn't realise this would be so complicated. Will try to give it a go. Thanks again.